# Android list view array adapter

Tags: android, list, view

I am implementing array list adopter uisng "simple_list_item_2" that is inbuilt but I get error. it says " getview from fragment cannot be applied" and it also cannot resolve "get" symbol from get.(position)

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

        ListView listView2;
        String[] items = {"Friendly Map", "Inc"};

        public AboutFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
            listView2 = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, items);
            listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            String[] entry = listView2.get(position);

            return view;

        }


    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8166497/3790150

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

        ListView listView2;
        String[] items = {"Friendly Map", "Inc"};

        public AboutFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
            listView2 = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, items);
            listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            View view = convertView;
            String entry = listView2.get(position);

            return view;

        }


    }
```